How to make custom file uploading with progress bar in gradio?
I want to make my own uploading function with progress bar in Gradio, cause for some reason, gradio.File uploader is broken (it's progress bar is not displayed in some cases), so I've tried to use gradio.UploadButton intead, like this:
import gradio as gr
import time


def upload_file(file, progress=gr.Progress()):
    progress(0, desc="Starting")
    for i in progress.tqdm([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], desc="Uploading"):
        time.sleep(2)
        progress(i / 5, desc="Uploadin")
    return file.name


with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    file_output = gr.File()
    upload_button = gr.UploadButton(
        "Click to Upload a File", file_types=["image", "video"], file_count="single"
    )
    upload_button.upload(upload_file, inputs=upload_button, outputs=file_output)

demo.launch()

But, it's not working as I want, because:

I dont know how to make actual tqdm of my own actual uploading process.
upload event listener is triggerd only AFTER default uploading is finished, not at the start
Default uploading is still active, so I can't control the output folder, and I can't make tqdm of my own actual uploading process.

